# acces apache from local network

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

I want to access an apache2 server from another computer in the same LAN. Generally it's working, but I can't see Images and scripts included by 
    "script src=" 
aren't "visible" as well. I'm hosting a wordpress Blog on the local server. it is not located in ../www/ but in ~/public_html/.
All the files and dirs in ~/public_html/wordpress/ have permissions for "others" to list, access, write and change (for testing matters).

When i view the site locally by http://127.0.0.1/~user/wordpress/ everything works fine!
It's just when I try to view the page from some other Computer in the LAN (http://192.168.2.142/~user/wordpress/).

the access.log says this to it:

```
$ cat /var/log/apache2/access.log | grep 192.

192.168.2.167 - - [07/Nov/2011:16:15:03 +0100] "GET /~user/wordpress/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1327      "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.18) Gecko/20110628 Ubuntu/10.04     (lucid) Firefox/3.6.18"
```

so code 200 is indicating everything is all right, or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely issue is that you scripts are always attempting to load files from the local machine rather than the remote machine. You can verify this by looking at the source of the page. The fact that you aren't seeing errors in your logs indicates that the requests aren't getting to the machine.

The way to solve this is to make sure that you have the correct domain configured in WP. This can be modified in wp-config.php. Make sure that it is set to the network address of this machine (ie. 192.168.2.142).

Comment: this did the trick.. very stupid of me, indeed. thanks a lot!